# PVLIB decomposing for standard components

Tags: pvlib

My question is about the PVlib library. We download some data using forecast.py. Not sure that this file does clear sky scaling/decomposing on the GHI/DNI/DHI. Then it finally gives us timeseries data. As next step, we calculate irradiance using these standard components. Here,

Do we need clear sky decomposition again? Or

Using these ghi/dni/dhi values, is it enough to calculate irradiance correctly? For example,

poa = irradiance.get_total_irradiance(
surface_tilt
surface_azimuth
solar_zenith
solar_azimuth
ghi
dni
dhi
dni_extra
albedo
surface_type
model ='perez',
model_perez ='allsitescomposite1990')

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Mutlu, can you post a complete script with the code you're asking about?  Text descriptions are easy to misinterpret.  Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, we obtain irradiance components using forecast.py. forecast.py gives us processed data. Next,  I would like calculate poa irrad. using this function:            
poa = irradiance.get_total_irradiance . This function uses the ghi/dni/dhi as input , also other parameters. We have already obtained these standard irradiance components using forecast.py. Can we use these params directly for calculating poa irradiance or do we need extra process on these ghi/dni/dhi components before using in the function of get_total_irradiance. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mutlu I do not see why you should not be able to use the ghi/dni/dhi you have obtained. Is there a reason you are skeptical of using them? For further help, it would be great if you could update the original question with a minimal code example.